# Arrow keys and changing control's focus hang the application

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I have a usercontrol that contains a `FlowLayoutPanel` (topdown flow) with a bunch of radiobuttons.  The control exposes a `CheckedChanged` event that fires whenever one of the radiobuttons's check changed.

My form contains the usercontrol and a textbox.  I subscribe the usercontrol's `CheckedChanged` event and depending on which radiobutton gets checked, I either disable the textbox or put a focus inside the textbox.

All this works fine with mouseclick when changing the radiobutton's check state.  However, this will hang indefinitely when using the arrow keys. I don't understand why the difference.

The following are steps to reproduce the behavior I'm seeing:

1. Create a usercontrol and drop a `FlowLayoutPanel` control and set its `FlowDirection = TopDown`. Then add two radiobuttons to the `FlowLayoutPanel`.
2. Provide an event handler in the usercontrol

   ```
   public event EventHandler CheckedChanged
   {
       add { radioButton2.CheckedChanged += value; }
       remove { radioButton2.CheckedChanged -= value; }
   }
   ```
3. Create a windows form and drop the above user control. Add a textbox and set `Enabled` to False.  Subscribe to the usercontrol's `CheckedChanged` event as follows

   ```
   private void userControl11_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       textBox1.Select();
   }
   ```
4. Run.  Notice that if you use the mouse to click between the radiobuttons, thing works fine; but it will crash if you use the up/down arrow keys.

Comment: I'm betting your question doesn't contain enough information to solve this. Can you cook up the simplest possible (fewest lines of code) test case that demonstrates the problem and add it here?

Comment: Solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970951

Answer (score 0):

```
public event EventHandler CheckedChanged
{
    add {
         radioButton2.CheckedChanged += value;
        }
    remove {
         radioButton2.CheckedChanged -= value;
        }
}
```

Hmm, `value` is uninitialized? Or am I missing something?