# Form not responding after navigation key is pressed in a UserControl form with RadioButtons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing the same issue raised in "[Arrow keys and changing control's focus hang the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920481/arrow-keys-and-changing-controls-focus-hang-the-application)".  Since I'm unable to comment on it due to I don't have enough points.  Hence, I posted a new one.

Thanks in advance.

1. Run the program
2. Select any radiobutton
3. Click button2
4. Press tab to focus onto radiobutton
5. Press Left/Right Navigation keys
6. Form hang-up (not responding).

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucPage11.BringToFront();
        ucPage11.Enabled = true;
        richTextBox1.Enabled = false; 
    }

    private void ucPage11_SelectionChanged()
    {
        ucPage11.Enabled = false;
        richTextBox1.BringToFront();
        richTextBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

UserControl.cs
- The user control has 3 radio button control in it.

```
public delegate void SelectionEventHandler();

public partial class UCPage1 : UserControl
{
    //private ToggleImageControlManager toggleImgCtrlMgr;

    public UCPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event SelectionEventHandler SelectionChanged;

    private void RBO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectionChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can start with adding some `Debug.Print` first. I'm suspecting whether the events are circular called.

Comment: Thank Lei.  I added the debug.print on RBO_Click, button2_Click and ucPage11_SelectionChanged. I ran the program and the Debug window is not updating after I did the above steps.

Comment: what about `Debug.WriteLine`?

Comment: Got the same result.  Same scenario as Debug.Print

Comment: can you test `Debug.WriteLine` in a brand new default winform project? you should first make sure visual studio is working as expected.

Comment: Hello Lei, I can confirm that the visual studio is working as expected.  I'm on debug mode and viewing the Output window. It fires fine but without pressing Left/Right Navigation keys.  I then tested it by using a FlowLayoutPanel instead of the UserControl and its working.  Though on the other hand the UC doesn't work.  Thank you for your patience Lei. I appreciate it.

Comment: put all you code to github and let me debug?

Comment: Hello Lei, I isolated the issue.  When you put the radiobutton within a panel, flowlayoutpanel or tablelayoutpanel of your UserControl the issue persist when you follow the above  steps.  Apologies if I haven't add that on my above question.

Comment: in stackoveflow it's best for you to show a minimal, reproducible code. but apparently above code cannot be copy-pasted and run, so nobody is patient enough to read it.

Comment: Thanks Lei, I was able to solve it after a long read and research.  Apologies. For I wasn't able to show a minimal code, though the form and usercontrol that I built contains only minimal control and default settings (UserControl with FlowLayoutPanel and in it has 3 radiobutton each of the button is referenced to one event RBO_Click.  The form only contains the usercontrol and a button.  UserControl has an event registered as shown in my post).  

The changes I made was to change `SelectionChanged?.Invoke();` to 
`this?.BeginInvoke(new Action(SelectionChanged), null);`.

Comment: c# events should rather be invoked like this `handler(this, e);` see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/). i see no reason to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`, these two functions are more often used in multi-threading, or when the event name is known only in run time.